# Can you plot interquartile range as the error band on a seaborn lineplot?

Tags: python, graph, seaborn, line-plot

I'm plotting time series data using seaborn lineplot (https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html), and plotting the median instead of mean. Example code:

```
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fmri = sns.load_dataset("fmri")
ax = sns.lineplot(x="timepoint", y="signal", estimator = np.median, data=fmri)
```

I want the error bands to show the interquartile range as opposed to the confidence interval. I know I can use `ci = "sd"` for standard deviation, but is there a simple way to add the IQR instead? I cannot figure it out.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think you can do it through `lineplot`. You will probably have to calculate it yourself and draw it onto the plot using matplotlib

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't know if this can be done with seaborn alone, but here's one way to do it with matplotlib, keeping the seaborn style. The `describe()` method conveniently provides summary statistics for a DataFrame, among them the quartiles, which we can use to plot the medians with inter-quartile-ranges.

```py
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fmri = sns.load_dataset("fmri")
fmri_stats = fmri.groupby(['timepoint']).describe()

x = fmri_stats.index
medians = fmri_stats[('signal', '50%')]
medians.name = 'signal'
quartiles1 = fmri_stats[('signal', '25%')]
quartiles3 = fmri_stats[('signal', '75%')]

ax = sns.lineplot(x, medians) 
ax.fill_between(x, quartiles1, quartiles3, alpha=0.3);
```

[image: quartile plot]

Comment: Thank you @Arne, this is great!

Answer (score 7):

You can calculate the median within lineplot like you have done, set ci to be none and fill in using `ax.fill_between()`

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fmri = sns.load_dataset("fmri")
ax = sns.lineplot(x="timepoint", y="signal", estimator = np.median, 
                  data=fmri,ci=None)

bounds = fmri.groupby('timepoint')['signal'].quantile((0.25,0.75)).unstack()
ax.fill_between(x=bounds.index,y1=bounds.iloc[:,0],y2=bounds.iloc[:,1],alpha=0.1)
```

[image]

Comment: This is great, thank you! I'm not sure if I should accept yours or @Arne's answer as the correct one given they're similar?

Answer (score 1):

This option is possible since version `0.12` of seaborn, see [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/error_bars) for the documentation.

`pip install --upgrade seaborn`

The estimator specifies the point by the name of pandas method or callable, such as 'median' or 'mean'.

The `errorbar` is an option to plot a distribution spread by a string, (string, number) tuple, or callable. In order to mark the median value and fill the area between the interquartile, you would need the params:

```py
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fmri = sns.load_dataset("fmri")
ax = sns.lineplot(data=fmri, x="timepoint", y="signal", estimator=np.median, 
                  errorbar=lambda x: (np.quantile(x, 0.25), np.quantile(x, 0.75)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can now!

```
estimator="median", errobar=("pi",0.5)
```

https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/error_bars